# Restricted low-ascii character in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ascii

Im having an error while trying to compile an .air from Flash CS5.5. The error says:

Usage error (incorrect arguments)
Filename contains restricted low-ascii character 13:

Im using a version of the file which compiles correctly on XP, now Im trying to compile on OsX but it doesn't. Any clue?.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Different operating systems use different characters to mark the end of line:

- Unix / Linux / OS X uses LF (line feed, '\n', 0x0A)
- Macs prior to OS X use CR (carriage return, '\r', 0x0D)
- Windows / DOS uses CR+LF (carriage return followed by line feed, '\r\n', 0x0D0A)

In your case, ascii 13 = carriage return.

It is probable that one of your air project configuration files has an embedded carriage return that is causing this error.

You should try a utility such as [linebreaks](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12045/linebreak)

Less likely but not impossible, is that one of your actual file names contains a carriage return.

For that you will need to try and rename the files till you find the correct one.